# VBA - Calling from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Trying to delete sheets based on data from another workbook sheet - By comparing and accessing data from another workbook sheet, however its not working. I was able to do it if the sheet was in the same workbook, however i do not want to import the worksheet every time.

Code so far, My problem is calling from another workbook sheet.

```
sub delete()
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim wks As Worksheet
     Dim MyRange As Range
     Dim Cell As Range
     Set wb = Workbooks("name.xlsx")
     Set wks = wb.Worksheets("allnames")
     With wks
        Set MyRange = wks.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
     End With
     On Error Resume Next
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     For Each Cell In MyRange
         Sheets(Cell.Value).Delete
     Next Cell
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which workbooks sheets are you willing to delete?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub delete()
     Dim toDeleteSheetsWb As Workbook
     Dim Cell As Range

     Set toDeleteSheetsWb = Workbooks("WorkbookWithSheetsToDelete.xlsx") '<-- set the workbook whose sheets will be deleted (change "WorkbookWithSheetsToDelete.xlsx" to its actual name)
     With Workbooks("name.xlsx").Worksheets("allnames") '<-- reference the worksheet from which to read worksheets names to be deleted in "WorkbookWithSheetsToDelete.xlsx" workbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each Cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            toDeleteSheetsWb.Sheets(Cell.Value).delete
        Next Cell
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so essentially i want to cross reference the current workbook(1) sheet with another workbooks(2) sheets data, if the name of the title appears in workbook(2) column(A:A), it will then search workbook(1) sheets and delete the sheets if the name appear/matches in workbook(2) data column (A:A).

Thanks.

Comment: it seems to me you only need to take my code and substitute `Workbooks("WorkbookWithSheetsToDelete.xlsx")` with `Workbooks(1)` and  `Workbooks("name.xlsx")` with `Workbooks(2)`. Thus assuming 1) workbooks must have been _chronologically_ opened in the correct order, since `Workbooks(1)` refers to the 1st opened workbook and `Workbooks(2)` refers to the 2nd opened workbook in current Excel session 2) `Workbooks(2)` sheet that has sheet names in its column "A" is named after "allnames" (otherwise change it to the actual one). Let me know