# VBA Delete Sheet with Display Alerts False Still Alerting From Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot delete the sheet using a macro that is being called from another Excel workbook.  I've looked at a few Stack [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146021/vba-calling-from-another-workbook) but still getting the alert when calling the macro.  I found a workaround but I'm frustrated the pop up wouldn't turn off.

**How can I disable the Alert when calling from another workbook?**

```
    Set aFile = GetObject(aWB)
    sheetName = "_DataToPDF"
    On Error Resume Next
    
    wsCount = aFile.Worksheets.Count
    
    For i = 1 To wsCount
        If aFile.Worksheets(i).Name = sheetName Then           
            aFile.DisplayAlerts = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False    '<- This has turned off previously but failing now
            Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
                'aFile.Sheets(sheetName).Delete
                aFile.Worksheets(i).Delete
            Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
            aFile.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
```

[image: excel-vba-image-delete-ws]

Comment: `aFile.Application.DisplayAlerts = False`... remove that `On Error Resume Next` too. `aFile.DisplayAlerts = False` is quite wrong.

Comment: The two workbooks may be open in different instances of the Excel application. Assign each instance to its own variable and then disable alerts for the instance in which you delete the worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference to the instance of Excel that the workbook is in:

```
aFile.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Also, remove the `On Error Resume Next`. It's hiding some errors, including the ones thrown by the lines

```
aFile.DisplayAlerts = False
...
aFile.DisplayAlerts = False
```

as a `Workbook` does not have a `DisplayAlerts` property.